# This not applicable to target 'member propertty without backing field or delegate' and passing value error with Room on Android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I am using Room. I need to use SELETC, INSERT, DELETE all.

This is what I implemented:

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE m_id IN (:m_id)")
    fun loadAllByIds(userSeqs: IntArray?): List<User?>?

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    val all: List<User?>?
}
```

```
@Entity(tableName = "user")
data class User (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val seq: Long,

    // this name is used in dao as column name
    @ColumnInfo(name = "m_id") val mId: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "k_id") var kId: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "created_at") var createdAt: String?
)
```

```
@Database(entities = {User.class}, version = 1,  exportSchema = false)
public abstract class MyDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public static final String DB_NAME = "MyDatabase.db";
    private static MyDatabase INSTANCE;
    public abstract UserDao userDao();

    public static MyDatabase getMyDatabase(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context, MyDatabase.class, DB_NAME).build();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public static void destroyInstance() {
        INSTANCE = null;
    }
}
```

`@Query("SELECT * FROM deliver")` says

> This not applicable to target 'member property without backing field or delegate'

`@get:Query("SELECT * FROM deliver")` make it disappear. But, I don't know why it does. Does it solve the problem? What does it do?

Answer (score 7):

The `@Query` annotation is to be placed on a method. A kotlin property is kind of "a field + getter method + setter method", but it's not a field or a method per se. When you specify the annotation target via `@get:Query`, you are basically telling the compiler to put this annotation on the property's getter method, which makes the whole thing work.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, I figure out a solution by checking my import.

I am using retrofit and Room, by mistake I imported retrofit `@Query` version instead of a room. Please check your import as well.

Comment: I think it can happen. :) But it was not my case.

Comment: This was my issue, Thanks!